# Прогрузка фото на сайтах

Tags: html, css

можете подсказать если я сделаю див с display: none изначально и потом сделаю его блоком, фото загрузится когда див станет блоком или-же оно загружается сразу при заходе на сайт без вариантов? Новичок в этом плане, извиняюсь

Comment: Загрузится у пользователя*

Comment: Глянь, ниже примеры под ответом, исправили, в общем я ошибся с начала, есть обстоятельства при которых оно не загрузиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сегодня ваш браузер (в зависимости от версии) может пропустить загрузку изображения, если оно скрыто.

Если изображение имеет display:none, правило может быть прочитано сценарием и браузер не загружает изображения если оно скрыто.

В коментах пару примеров.

Comment: Не факт что фото будет загружено. Вопросе нет уточнения о том как вставлено фото. Вполне возможна ситуация что div имеет `style="background: url(...)"` и в таком случе фото будет загружено только в момент отображения блока

Comment: Вы же в ответе сами написали обратное. Вот записал пример: https://imgur.com/KCgl5mZ. Можете в инспекторе сами потыкать: https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/KKQjJey.

Comment: @Ein слшуай!, беру свои слова обратно ты был прав!, уже новые движки браузеров так и делают, я тут выполз спустя три года. Во че накопал. 210

Browsers are getting smarter. Today your browser (depending on the version) might skip the image loading if it can determine it's not useful.

The image has a display:none style but its size may be read by the script. Chrome v68.0 does not load images if the parent is hidden.

Comment: @Ein правда это касается <img> у родителя, но сути это не меняет, это так же может работать и с уралми css